# How do you apply light sources using OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to find any tutorial or sample code which explains and shows the usage of lights in OpenGL ES 2.0. Most of the material I have seen online refers to Opengl ES 1.1.

Can anyone provide any links or documentation on how to do lighting in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question.. Is anybody aware of any tutorials which show how to implement a light source using shaders?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difficulty with OpenGL ES 2.0 is that since you can write your own shaders pretty much how you want, there's no one set way to provide lighting to an object. It will depend on how you want to present your content.

That said, you can replicate OpenGL ES 1.1's fixed function lighting capabilties by doing something like providing a light direction and calculating the light intensity at each vertex. You can see an example of this in [this sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip) I slapped together for one of my classes.

The vertex shader used here is the following:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 normal;

varying float lightIntensity;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;

void main()
{
    vec4 newNormal = modelViewProjMatrix * normal;
    vec4 newPosition = modelViewProjMatrix * position;
    gl_Position = newPosition;

    lightIntensity = max(0.0, dot(newNormal.xyz, lightDirection));
}
```

with the matching fragment shader:

```
varying highp float lightIntensity;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 yellow = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4((yellow * lightIntensity * 0.2).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

The dot product of the light direction and the normal at that vertex is used to calculate the light intensity hitting the eye of the viewer from that vertex. This light intensity is then interpolated between the vertices in each triangle to give you the intensity at each fragment.

I do some more advanced per-pixel lighting in my open source [Molecules](http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) application, where each sphere and cylinder is really a raytraced impostor residing within a rectangle. For each pixel, I calculate the specular and ambient lighting contribution at that point on the virtual object, and then combine that with an ambient occlusion factor calculated at the loading of the model. That's far on the other extreme of what you can do with lighting, but you can dig into the code there or read [my little writeup](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2011/05/08/enhancing-molecules-using-opengl-es-20) on how this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad I think this code will prove to be very helpful .. I spent many many hours on this problem and I think the source code that you provided will most definitely help me get to the finish line. I will post my experiences in a little while .. PS. I wish there was a way to add more than 1 reputation point

Comment: @user1200008 - You might also be interested in my iTunes U course, where you can find the OpenGL ES 2.0 class that I used this for: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewCourse?id=497193807&s=143441&ls=1

Comment: Actually I have a question. As of now my geometry consists of a simple cube. I wanted to know how would I calculate the normals for this?

Comment: @Abhi - If you wanted to provide them per each vertex, you could just use the vertex coordinates, normalized to a distance of 1 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1). If you wanted to use indices and define the normals per face, then you'd want to calculated the directions orthogonal to each face (probably (1, 0, 0), etc.).

Comment: Ok .. After some trial and error and after following the link at this location http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/lighting-and-normals-r1682 I was able to calculate the normals for a cube. But I have a feeling that the normals will need to be recalculated when the cube is rotated/ scaled. Am I correct on this?

Comment: @Abhi - You shouldn't need to change the normals after scaling, and if you apply rotation like I do in the shader above you'll see that I'm also rotating the normals to match. If you change the actual vertices outside of this, you may need to change the normals too.

Comment: I see... Thanks so much for clearing that issue. Actually I have another question. I just finished making a poc using the code given by you as a base. However my cube looks completely black in color. I have a feeling that the cube is black in color because the line        lightIntensity = max(0.0, dot(newNormal.xyz, lightDirection)); is always returning 0. Any other ideas? In my render function I logged the arrays feeding the values to newNormal and light direction ... Both are non zero. What am I missing

Comment: @Abhi - Check the direction of your light source. If it's pointing from the rear of the object, you won't see anything. You can verify your normals are correct by writing them out as your fragment color, then checking the RGB values there.

Comment: Ok ... I think I figured out the problem ... The normals that I am passing for each vertex is always 0. Why would that be? I am trying to render a cube. A cube should have 12 triangle faces which means 12 normals. I print my normals in the render functions and I do get 12 * 3 (x,y,z) values .... Do I need to send the values for normals to the vertex buffer objects?

Comment: Some more information... Dont know how relevant this is but     glVertexAttribPointer(_simpleLightNormalAttribute, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float), (GLvoid*) (0)); If I set the size value to 4 I see some sort of light but if I see the value to 3 (which in my opinion) is the correct value I see the blue cube.