# Creating "light sources" inside a tinted layer for Day/Night system

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've played around with SKLightNode that Sprite Kit provides. It's nifty but I'm trying to attain a very specific visual effect inside my RPG for my Day & Night system. So far, I use a tinted layer like so:

```
@implementation aScene
{
    /*IVARS*/
    SKShapeNode *tint;
}

//Tints the entire screen.
-(void)tint
{
    //CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _screenWidth, _screenHeight);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _backgroundLayer.layerSize.width, _backgroundLayer.layerSize.height);

    tint = [SKShapeNode node];

    CGPathRef thePath = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);

    tint.path           = thePath;
    tint.fillColor      = [UIColor blackColor];
    tint.strokeColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
    //tint.position = CGPointMake(_backgroundLayer.layerSize.width/2, _backgroundLayer.layerSize.height/2);
    tint.zPosition      = 0.9; //20.0;
    [_worldNode addChild:tint];
    tint.alpha          = 0;

    SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.7 duration:1.0];
    [tint runAction:fadeIn];
}
```

Then I call that bad boy with this [self tint]; and remove it with this [tint removeFromParent];

Question: is there any way to completely fade through specific areas in the tint layer? Inside those "spots" I will add SKSpriteNode's that look like lamps. This is what I am aiming for:
http://peekychew.deviantart.com/art/Forthold-City-Night-time-341851278

If this isn't possible, are there any other techniques or tricks?

Comment: SKLightNode didn't achieve the effects you wanted?

Comment: Well there's the problem with the super long shadows - I am unable to drastically shorten them. Plus the performance hit gradually grows and I have A LOT of physicsBodies representing buildings, NPC's and other stuff. That forces a lot of calculations to happen. Plus, I am unable to make the light source "pierce" through the night/tint in the areas where the light originates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SK doesn't really have a lot of support for lighting features right now. You can either go with SKLightNode, which is a all or nothing kinda class, or you can dive deep into OpenGL.

Either way you will have to use darker shade map tiles to create a night time ambience for your map and lighter shade tiles for daytime. This of course means creating the same map twice using different tile sets.

If you decide on using SKLightNode, I suggest you disable the casting of shadows as this uses up a lot of cycles and is a all or nothing features. No gradients or falloffs at all. You can use the light source features to give an illumination effect for lights and your player.

If you decide on OpenGL there are a bunch of different ways to go. Brad Larson answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502804/how-do-you-apply-light-sources-using-opengl-es-2-0) on "How do you apply light sources using OpenGL ES 2.0". You also google "ios OpenGL light source" which brings up a bunch of links on the subject.